# storing data in another form protection issues

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, access-modifiers

I'm trying to store a string from one form to a label on another from. However, when doing so it says it cannot be done because of its protection level. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
 maskedTxtLogin.Text = FormInvisible.lblInitials.Text();
```

Comment: create a custom event for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

The controls are generated as a *private* field in your form designer:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblInitials;
```

If you want to access them outside of the form you need to create a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) for them. To see the above declaration and write a property for that, just right click on your `lblInitials` in your code and click *Go to Declaration* (or *Definition*), in the class that you are navigated to write the following code:

```
public Label LblInitials
{
    get { return lblInitials; }
    set { lblInitials= value; }
}
```

Also you need to create a new instance of your form to access this property:

```
FormInvisible fr = new FormInvisible();
maskedTxtLogin.Text = fr.LblInitials.Text;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184839/discussion-on-answer-by-s-akbari-storing-data-in-another-form-protection-issues).

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to change the protection level

Open `FormInvisible.Designer.cs`

Look for `private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblInitials;`

Modify the access modifier from `private` to `public`

or you can open the property of the control and change **`Modifiers`**  from **`private`** to **`public`**

[image]

Comment: It is really considered as a bad practice to change the protection of the **fields** from `private` to `public`. Never do that and try to use **properties** always!

Comment: @S.Akbari Of course, this is absolutely true,
your solution is better. 
this solution 
just to offer another way to solve the problem